# ldap3 operation: SEARCH seems to fail (search_filter syntax vs RFC4515)

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.8, python-ldap

Edit: tl;dr - The `search_filter` argument used in SEARCH might be non conforming with RFC4515.

I've got a Django server running version 1.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using Python 3.4 and for that I'm trying to configure LDAP authentication using [ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.org/index.html).

This is part of an upgrade to the versions named above from 1.6.2, 12.04, and 2.7.3, respectively. Everything was working correctly, so I assume that the problem is on my end and not with the authentication server.

The way this works is I've got a file called *authenticate_user.py* which receives the username and password passed through an HTML form as shown below.

```
def authenticateStudent(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    logger.info("User " + username + " has logged in.")
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    x = Auth(username, password)
    retVal = x.AuthenticatePy()
    logger.info('retVale is '+str(retVal)) #this returns False
    #more code and more logging
```

The method instantiates an object from the Auth class (shown below), stores the username and password within, and then calls the AuthenticatePy() method in that class.

```
import logging
import sys
import os.path,subprocess
import ldap3 as ldap
from ldap3 import Connection, Server, SIMPLE, SYNC, SUBTREE, ALL


logger = logging.getLogger('Submission')

class Auth():

    studentName = ""
    studentEmail = ""
    studentMatrik = ""

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def AuthenticatePy(self):
        user_dn = "cn="+self.username+",ou=users,ou=data,ou=prod,ou=authserver,dc=domain,dc=tld"
        base_dn = "dc=domain,dc=tld"
        server = Server("authserver.domain.tld", port=636, use_ssl=True)

        filter = "uid="+self.username #might be incorrect
        try:
            #if authentication successful, get the full user data
            connect = Connection(server, user=user_dn, password=self.password)
            connect.bind()
            logger.info('Connection Bind Complete!') #the last logged message from this method
            result = connect.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter=filter, search_scope=SUBTREE)
            logger.info('SEARCHING COMPLETE') #does not appear in the log
            # return all user data results
            connect.unbind()
            uname = result[0][1]['cn'][0]
            studentName = result[0][1]['fullName'][0]
            studentEmail = result[0][1]['imHauptEMail'][0]
            studentMatrik = result[0][1]['imMatrikelNr'][0]
            logger.info('studentName is '+str(studentName))
            if uname == self.username :
                return studentName + '$' + studentEmail + '$' + studentMatrik
            else:
                return False
        except ldap.LDAPExceptionError:
            connect.unbind()
            return False
```

The last log message I'm seeing is 'Connection Bind Complete!' and I'm not really sure what's breaking. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've been troubleshooting this for a while and I'm beginning to think that the problem could be in the `search_filter` argument I'm passing the search function. The [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searches.html) documentation on the SEARCH operation states that the filter string should be RFC4515 compliant, and I'm not sure I'm providing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. My syntax for the `search_filter` argument was indeed wrong.

It needed to be set as mentioned in the other answer:
`filter = "(uid="+self.username + ")"`

However, I also needed to indicate which attributes I wanted to return, hence `connect.search()`'s arguments needed to be changed:

```
connect.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter=filter, search_scope=SUBTREE, attributes=['cn', 'fullName', 'imHauptEmail', 'imMatrikelNr'])
```

Also, accessing the returned attributes doesn't work the same way it did in the `python-ldap` library for Python 2.7 and can be accessed by `connect.response`, which is a list of dictionaries. You would have to access these attributes before you unbind the connection, so the `connect.unbind()` was moved until after storing the values needed from the attributes.

```
uname = str(connect.response[0]['attributes']['cn'][0])
studentName = str(connect.response[0]['attributes']['fullName'][0])
studentEmail = str(connect.response[0]['attributes']['imHauptEMail'][0])
studentMatrik = str(connect.response[0]['attributes']['imMatrikelNr'][0])
connect.unbind()
```

In reality all of this is explained in the [documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.org/searches.html) (See the examples section at the bottom). I just needed to read it a few times to get it.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the author of ldap3. The ldap filter must be included in parenthesis. Please try adding leading and traling parenthesis to the filter:

filter = "(uid="+self.username + ")"

Bye,
Giovanni